# Opening docx file via R on Mac

Tags: r

I want to open a docx file via R on Mac but it does not work. Actually I want to open a *.command file but before I break anything I want to open a docx file to be sure everything works. At first I tried

```
file.show("path/path/xyz.docx")
```

but this tries to save a file. I want to open it though.

Then I tried

```
shell.exec("path/path/xyz.docx")
```

but this only seems to work on windows.

Then I tried

```
system2("path/path/xyz.docx")
```

but it says "command not found".

How do I open a file from R on a Mac?

Comment: Have you tried `system2("open path/path/xyz.docx")` (ref: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/212583)

Comment: Thank you. The system2 command did not work. But ´system('open xyz.docx')´ worked. You need to be in the right directory within the shell. Seemingly you can find/change the directory with regular r commands outside the system() command: getwd()/setwd(). If you add it as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Comments by @MrFlick and me below the question solved it.